# How do I get the previous tag in github actions and then compare it to the current tag?

Tags: tags, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm setting up continuous deployment with github actions which I want to run every time a tag is created.
However I only want to deploy if there has not been a major bump (Using semver for versions) since the last tag.

I have only been able so far to find actions/examples that get the current tag, not the one before. like (https://github.com/WyriHaximus/github-action-get-previous-tag)

How would I do this?

Edit: (thanks for the tip on `git fetch -a`) I managed to get it working with `git tag` and `cut`

```yaml
      - name: Get major of current tag and previous tag
        id: vars
        run: |
          git fetch -a
          echo ::set-output name=current_major::$(git tag --sort "-committerdate" | cut -d$'\n' -f1 | cut -d. -f1)
          echo ::set-output name=previous_major::$(git tag --sort "-committerdate" | cut -d$'\n' -f2 | cut -d. -f1)
```

Comment: You can use git commands in your workflows, and access the repo tags using `actions/checkout` with the `fetch:0` arg and your `access token`. Therefore if you perform a `git fetch -a` afterward you can access all tags available in the repo. I used something similar in [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/20-generate-patch-tag-cherry-pick.yml) if you look for a reference.

Comment: We support this via Reliza Hub - with getlatestrelease cli command - i.e. see sample here - https://github.com/Mafia-Demo/mafia-deployment/blob/master/.github/workflows/reliza.yml (line 21 and below). Essentially you capture tag information on Reliza Hub and then retrieve it on the next run. Feel free to join our Discord, will help you with specific implementation - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ